# Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. in Wordpress debug mode

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
wp_enqueue_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like/post-like.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post-like', 'mytheme_post_like');
add_action('wp_ajax_post-like', 'mytheme_post_like');
```

The **Code above is working** and my postlike system is working fine like that, however Im getting **Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly.** in wordpress debug mode but its working.

When I try to do it as a function in the right way the like buttons not working the javascript is broken and also when I try to add this only for single pages using the  `if( !is_admin() && is_single() ) {` the javascript is brtoken too, the like dislike buttons not working.

Can u help me on this? How can I get this in the right way and only for the single pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gazi_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
function gazi_theme_enqueue_styles(){
   wp_enqueue_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like/post-like.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')     ));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post-like', 'mytheme_post_like');
add_action('wp_ajax_post-like', 'mytheme_post_like');
```